# Using GNU Parallel for cluster computing over LAN with rsync

Tags: bash, multiprocessing, gnu-parallel

I have two machines, and I want to use GNU Parallel to have multiple processes 'cat' the contents of some text files from both machines.

I have the following setup.

On a local machine, in the same directory, I have the following files:

- cmd.sh - a bash file with contents: 'cat "$@"'
- test1.txt - a text file with contents: 'Test 1'
- test2.txt - a text file with contents: 'Test 2'
- test3.txt - a text file with contents: 'Test 3'
- nodefile - a text file with the following contents:

  2/:

  4/ dan@192.168.0.3

This is if I am using the nodefile example from wordpress link (below), and my IP is 192.168.0.2.

None of these files are replicated on the remote machine. I want to have multiple processes 'cat' the contents of each of the test?.txt files from both machines.

Preferably, this:

- Wouldn't leave any artifacts on the remote machine
- Would leave the contents of the local directory intact.

I have been able to execute multiprocessing commands remotely with the nodefile as per [this wordpress example](https://spectraldifferences.wordpress.com/2015/04/26/execute-commands-on-multiple-computers-using-gnu-parallel-setting-up-a-cluster-on-the-cheap/), but none involving file echoing remotely.

So far, I have something like the following:

```
parallel --sshloginfile nodefile --workdir . --basefile cmd.sh -a cmd.sh --trc ::: test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
```

But this isn't working and is removing the files from my directory and not replacing them, as well as giving rsync errors. I (unfortunately) can't provide the errors at the moment, or replicate the setup.

I am very inexperienced with parallel, can anyone guide me on the syntax to accomplish this task? I haven't been able to find the answer (so far) in the man pages or on the web.

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and using latest version of GNU Parallel.

Comment: It is unclear if you want to 'cat' the content or 'echo' the filename.

Comment: You are right, I changed it to cat. Was going from memory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make a few mistakes:

- -a is used to give an input source. It is basically an alias for ::::
- you do not give the command to run after the options to GNU Parallel and before the :::
- --trc takes an argument (namely the file to transfer back). You do not have a file to transfer back, so use `--transfer --cleanup` instead.

So:

```
chmod +x cmd.sh
parallel --sshloginfile nodefile --workdir . --basefile cmd.sh --transfer --cleanup ./cmd.sh ::: test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
```

It is unclear if you want to transfer anything to the remote machine, so maybe this is really the correct answer:

```
parallel --sshloginfile nodefile --nonall --workdir . ./cmd.sh test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
```

Comment: This solution works, but deletes the local copies of file cmd.sh and one of the text files each run.

Comment: If you do not want to transferred files to be removed, remove '--cleanup'.

Comment: I want the files to be transferred to the remote machine and then cleaned up from the remote machine. I want the files on the local machine to remain. Your first command is leaving the remote machine clean, but is also removing cmd.sh from the local machine. This is not desired behavior. Also, your second command is just 'cat'ing the contents locally and throwing a file not found error on the remote machine for cmd.sh

Comment: You are leaving something out: `cmd.sh` will not be removed on the local machine. So you are doing something that you are not writing. Do you possibly have a host in nodefile that is actually the local machine? If you want to have that that you need to replace it with ':'.

Comment: I do have my local machine referenced in the nodefile, it seems obvious now. Thanks!